Upload Image to Directory
How to upload an image to a folder without using move_uploaded_file() in PHP ?
Because we are not allowed to upload files to our server but I needed it just to upload an image to "assets/images" and remove it later. Thanks for the help in advance.

"we are not allowed to upload files" What does this mean? How are you prohibited?

Use ftp instead please

When you don't have permission to write files, you can't do it. But if you have a database, you can use an alternative method: Convert the file to a base64 string and store it in a database field
